# External Javascript function not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a novice web developer trying to use Firebase for my capstone project.

I'm trying to send HTML form input to the firebase DB using a function in an external js file that's declared earlier in the html file, but it keeps throwing the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: testThree is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick.

I'm using webpack, so all of my code is in a bundle.js file that's handling all of the javascript.

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

//this was taken from our firebase console, ask for source if inaccessible. Source: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/stubby-42865/settings/general/web:OGE0YTc1NTgtYjAyNy00NmFlLWExZTctYjExYTY3YzAzM2Ix?nonce=1674237869676
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    //Firebase config
};

// Initialize Firebase SDKs
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

//library imports
import { collection, doc, setDoc, getDoc, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

//TEST ONE: add a document to the cities collection
// Add a new document in collection "cities"
await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "LA"), {
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
});

//TEST TWO: read the document LA from the cities collection
const docTestRet = doc(db, "cities", "LA");
const docTestGet = await getDoc(docTestRet);

if (docTestGet.exists()) {
    console.log("Data: ", docTestGet.data())
} else {
    console.log("get fail");
}

//TEST THREE: add a document to the cities collection via HTML input
async function testThree() {
    const abbrEle = document.getElementById('abbr').value;
    const nameEle = document.getElementById('name').value;
    const countryEle = document.getElementById('country').value;
    const stateEle = document.getElementByID('state').value;
    await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", abbrEle), {
        name: nameEle,
        state: stateEle,
        country: countryEle,
    });
}
```

The function testThree is being sent to my index.html file, shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
    <!--Header for Home page. Displays navbar and image-->
    <header>
        <!-- <img src="../img/Stubby.png" style="height:50px;width:50px;border-radius:50%;background-color:#808080";/> -->
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/Calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/Help.html">Help</a></li>
            <li><img src="/img/Stubby.png" style="height:45px;width:45px;float:right" /></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <!--note: columns will inevitably have unequal height, the row class fixes it-->
    <div class="row">
        <!--Main column div class.-->
        <div class="column main">

            <h2>Main column</h2>
            <p>This column will have content in it garnered around supporting the chatbot. This would include stuff like timers, reminders, etc.</p>

        </div>

        <!--Chatbot column div class-->
        <div class="column chat">

            <h2>Chatbot column</h2>
            <p>This column will have the chatbot, its text window it uses to respond as well as our text window that we would use.</p>
            <form id="test">
                Abbreviation: <input type="text" id="abbr" name="abbr"><br>
                Country: <input type="text" id="country" name="country"><br>
                Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
                State: <input type="text" id="state" name="state"><br>
                <input type="button" onclick="testThree()" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--footer-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="footer">
            <h2>Footer</h2>
            <p> This is where our contact information, as well as significant contributions to our website will be! </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It should send data to the firestore database, but I keep getting the aforementioned error above. Another SO question had changed the onclick="function()" to onclick="function" that had helped, but it hasn't for me.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Edit: the way we fixed it was to use window.testThree = testThree to make the function global.

Comment: Small note: remember to load your bundle with `async` and `defer` attributes. You don't want it to block the page, and you don't want it to run before the initial DOM has been constructed. Having said that, if you're using modern ESM, _don't use onclick_, even MDN has a big red warning box about that in its article on [event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers). Find the elements that your JS code needs to hook into _in your JS code_ so that you know you're tying the right function(s) to the right element(s).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  this might be a dumb question, but is there anywhere i can find documentation on loading webpack w/ defer or async? Thank you for the advice!

Comment: It's not a webpack setting, they're attributes for the script element, so just `<script src="/dist/bundle.js" async defer></script>` and you're good to go.